# Wrapping an element inside an <a> element

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

When I use MVC i usually use

```
@Html.ActionLink("Awesome place", "Index", "Awesome")
```

But sometimes I'd like to put something inside that `<a>` tag, like a button.
And I end up with what you see below

```
<a href="/Awesome"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-12">Awesome place</button></a>
```

Is there a way to wrap things inside an ActionLink? Or just a better way for me to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Html.ActionLink` only works if you don't need anything but a text string inside the `<a></a>` tags. For every other scenario, just use `Url.Action`:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Awesome")">
    <!-- whatever -->
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

combine the bootstrap "button" class with the MVC helper

```
@Html.ActionLink("Awesome Place", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg" })
```